# How do I add heatsink vias on a pad?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I need to add vias on a pad to help act as a heat sink for some components (like in the link below).

D1 looks like it has some vias drilled through its largest pad (can see them from the bottom).

Will Altium let me add vias right on top of a pad like that, or do I have to do it a certain way to avoid errors?

https://www.ti.com/tool/LM25085MYEVAL#tech-docs

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try it and find out. Works as expected in OrCAD

Comment: Altium may think that is a fill rather than a pad. That is probably how I would do it. Place a fill so that it covers both pads for D1, then place vias in the fill.

Comment: Taking into account @Kyle B answer, I would simply suggest to have a look at altium documentation on vias stitching and shielding : https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/via-stitching-and-via-shielding-ad

Answer (score 3):

It's not a "Pad"... It's a "polygon fill".  And yes you can drop via's in it.

Draw the polygon first and tie it to the net you want, then drop vias.  The vias will automatically take the polygon net then.  If you do it other way round, the vias will be "no nets" and nothing gets connected

Also re: those pads in your example... They're not really optimal.   Note there is solder on the top layer, and the vias are in the same area.  It's easy for your solder to accidentally wick down the via.  It doesn't hurt the via, but it can starve your component of solder.   Check the 'tenting" box to lay solder mask over the via's to prevent this.